# Given order of two points, determining the number of points on an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

My problem is the following:

$E$ is an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + bx + c$ over integers modulo $221 = 13\cdot 17$.

There exist some points $P$ and $Q$ on $E$ such that $11P = \mathcal{O}$ and $7Q = \mathcal{O}$.

Can you determine $\sharp E$, the number of points on $E$?

---

What I've noted/tried:

- The order of $P$ is $11$ and the order of $Q$ is $7$.
- This looks an awful lot like [Schoof's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm). If I could use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to combine the results, how? What would I do with the result? I'm guessing something to do with $7\cdot 11 > 4\sqrt{221}$

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem:

Recall Lagrange's Theorem, which states that the order of any element in a group divides the number of elements in the group. Thus, $7 \mid \sharp E$ and $11 \mid \sharp E$. Therefore, $7\cdot 11 = 77 \mid \sharp E$.

By Hasse's Theorem, $\sharp E$ lies in the range $(221+1-2\sqrt{221},221+1+2\sqrt{221}) \approxeq (192,252)$. Thus, $\sharp E = 3 \cdot 77 = 231$.

Comment: Did you apply Hasse to $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{17}$ separately ? $\mathbb{Z}_{221}$ is not a field